# mhchem wrong subscript

Tags: mhchem

Using mhchem version 4 (ubuntu 15.10), the simple `\ce{CH2O}` inserted in a report document results in CH[t]2O with "[t]2" being in subscript. Am I missing something obvious (cant' see nothing related in mhchem manual)?

```
\documentclass[french]{report}
\makeatletter \makeatletter
\@namedef{ver@amsmath.sty}{}
\makeatother \usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage[load-configurations = abbreviations]{siunitx}
\sisetup{locale = FR,detect-all}
\sisetup{inter-unit-product=\ensuremath{\cdot}}
\makeatother \usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\title{\textsc{Bla}}
\author{NiFe}
\maketitle
\chapter{Blabla}
Blabla
\section{1}
\ce{CH2O}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hard to say, please provide a full minimal example that we can copy and test on our own systems (without having to add anything)

Comment: @NiFe a minimal example would be `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\begin{document}
\ce{CH2O}
\end{document}` (which works just fine for me)

Comment: Thanks, hope the following example is minimal enough:
\documentclass[french]{report}
\makeatletter
\makeatletter
\@namedef{ver@amsmath.sty}{}
\makeatother
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage[load-configurations = abbreviations]{siunitx}
\sisetup{locale = FR,detect-all}
\sisetup{inter-unit-product=\ensuremath{\cdot}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\title{\textsc{Bla}}
\author{NiFe}
\maketitle
\chapter{Blabla}
Blabla
\section{1}
\ce{CH2O}
\end{document}

Comment: Update the question, don't post it in a comment

Comment: What is that `\@namedef{ver@amsmath.sty}{}` doing? Remove it and the example works just fine.

Comment: @NiFe `\@namedef{ver@amsmath.sty}{}` prevents `mhchem` from loading `amsmath` but it *needs* `amsmath` in order to work properly!

Comment: Removing it, I got the following error: ! LaTeX Error: Command \iiint already defined. Will try to update my minimal example later, I need to run now.

Comment: Case solved, after removing the `\@namedef{ver@amsmath.sty}{}` I've explicitely loaded the amsmath package. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 2):

`\@namedef{ver@amsmath.sty}{}` fools `\RequirePackage{amsmath}` or `\usepackage{amsmath}` into thinking that `amsmath` is already loaded.

This prevents `mhchem` (or any other package) from loading `amsmath` but `mhchem` *needs* `amsmath` in order to work properly!

Remove the line and your example compiles file.